# Looking for script or software to pull from REST API and dump result into database

Tags: open-source, database, php

I'm working on a program that takes data from a bunch of different REST APIs and dumps their responses in a database every n minutes.  Basically creating a historical data warehouse of the API data.

I am looking for a piece of software that will run on php/mysql/linux (LAMP) that will automate this.  I'm currently creating jobs manually and making cron jobs that fire them off, which is working great- but looking for some software that might be able to automate this process.  Error handling is different for each API and it is becoming cumbersome.

Thanks!

Comment: But if you are 'working on a program', why not just program so that it does that for you; and have it run continuously?

Comment: @JanDoggen Why reinvent the wheel?  I'm looking for a solution so I don't have to code that part of it myself.

Comment: Fine with me, but I was only suggesting because all it takes is adding a timer and a few lines of code. Too bad I'm not fluent in php otherwise I would've written those here.